# Mounting cifs-share with kerberos fails: mount error(126): Required key not available

Tags: kerberos, samba, cifs

Recently mounting a samba-share by using Kerberos stopped working. The same share with the same mount options on another server works. So I assume there is nothing wrong with our DNS-Setup and or Active Directory Setup. Seems to be a client problem.

Output of

> mount share

```
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The fstab-entry looks like this:

```
//servername/share /home/username/share cifs _netdev,users,sec=krb5,noperm,noauto 0 0
```

Log shows this:

```
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: key description: cifs.spnego;0;0;39010000;ver=0x2;host=192.168.0.7;ip4=192.168.0.7;sec=krb5;uid=0x2b9d;creduid=0x2b9d;user=username;pid=0x68c6

Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: ver=2
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: host=192.168.0.7
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: ip=192.168.0.7
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: sec=1
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: uid=11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: creduid=11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: user=username
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: pid=26822
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: scandir error on directory '/run/user/11165': No such file or directory
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_11165 is valid ccache
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_11167
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_11167 is owned by 11167, not 11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_0
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_0 is owned by 0, not 11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_11176
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_11176 is owned by 11176, not 11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_11174
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_11174 is owned by 11174, not 11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_11308
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_11308 is owned by 11308, not 11165
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for 192.168.0.7
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: cifs_krb5_get_req: unable to get credentials for 192.168.0.7
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: failed to obtain service ticket (-1765328377)
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: Unable to obtain service ticket
Feb 21 10:01:11 clientserver cifs.upcall: Exit status -1765328377
```

Seems like the hostname resolution does not work correctly. I don't know how cifs.upcall gets the hostname but if I check the DNS records A,PTR seem to be ok. And netbios resolution does also work.

So how does kerberos lookup the hostname. Does it extract the hostname out of the UNC-Path?

Writing the Hostname into /etc/hosts does not work neither. Nevertheless another server with the same windbind, samba, cifs.upcall and kerberos Version does work. The resolv.conf has also the same entries.
There are some other samba-shares that work perfectly with kerberos. So I am a little bit stuck now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add '-t' option to invocation of cifs.upcall in /etc/request-key.d/

In my case (ubuntu) it was file /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf

Was:
create  cifs.spnego    * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k

Changed:
create  cifs.spnego    * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works! The -t Option does the following: With krb5 upcalls, the name used as the host portion of the service principal defaults to the hostname portion of the UNC. This option allows the upcall program to reverse resolve the network address of the server in order to get the hostname.

Comment: I don't really understand which kind of DNS problem I have, because dns lookups resolve fine on the ip address of the hostnames involved.

Comment: The problem was not with DNS resolving itself, but with the fact that by default it does not trust this DNS.

Comment: Note: this can even be the solution when the log shows a hostname!

Comment: Thank you, Alexander; this is absolutely the constructive answer the world needed. I've been chasing this bug (or seemingly-unimplemented edge-case-of-a-feature) on the Samba mailing lists for years, and all I find is unfruitful discussions dating back 13 years. But here you have a simple one-parameter change to Ubuntu's default config for CIFS-mount-getting-one-more-Kerberos-ticket, and now my Linux machines can follow proper DFS paths and resolve to a variety of file servers, all while consuming Kerberos credentials! Perfect!